# How to change url / routing in a MVC template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2019

In a Razor webtemplate I have following structure:

`pages\index.cshtml` >>> `localhost:9999/index` or `localhost:9999`

`pages\about.cshtml` >>> `localhost:9999/about`

and so on

In a MVC template I have...

`views\home\index.cshtml` >>> `localhost:9999/home` or `localhost:9999/home/index`
`views\home\about.cshtml` >>> `localhost:9999/home/about`

then I created a file in the views folder:

`views\test.cshtml`  >>> `localhost:9999/VIEWS/test.cshtml` ???

I get the error resource not found. And why Visual Studio makes VIEWS now in the url? Why the file extension?

when I type the url myself `localhost:9999/test.cshtml` or `localhost:9999/test` I have also the error resources not found.

I'm a bit confused.

What I finally want in the MVC template is...

`views\home\index.cshtml` >>> `localhost:9999`/ or `localhost:9999/index`
`views\home\about.cshtml` >>> `localhost:9999/about`

or

`views\index.cshtml` >>> `localhost:9999/` or `localhost:9999/index`

`views\about.cshtml` >>> `localhost:9999/about`

what do I have to change? I guess it's the routing, right?

Answer (score 0):

**Views** folder in created for **Controller** folder.

- This URL `localhost:9999/VIEWS/test.cshtml` only works if you have
  **ViewsController** and **test.cshtml** view inside the controller.
- If you want to be able to use this URL `localhost:9999/test`, you
  have to create **TestController** and create **Index** view inside the
  controller.

Hope you understand :)

Comment: OK. The **TestController** works. But I don't want to create a folder and a file for each page just to have an URL like  `localhost:9999/test`. This I can do with classic asp as well.

Is there a way to access cshtml files located direct in the Views folder?